# Magento2.3.1 In multistore email template logo not showing diffrent store wise?

Tags: multistore, email-templates, magento2.3.1, logo

In `Magneto 2.3.1` when I change in

**`Content -> Configuration -> Transactional Email -> Logo Image`**

After check, it only order email (like confirmation, invoice and shipment)there showing default `luma theme` logo, not update with uploaded logo but other email like.. contact and customer email there showing logo inside email  perfect. If any one idea related this issue please reply me

Thanks and appreciated for your reply.

Comment: its working fine - Content -> Configuration -> Transactional Email -> Logo Image, can you please clear cache....

Comment: already i try this